# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed due to images

Tags: python, machine-learning

i keep getting the error open cv assertation failed and i think my images are ok and beem trying lots of codes not getting any results pls help. trying to create a classifier that reads wether an images is a plate number or not.

```
def read_image(file_path):
  img = cv2.imread(file_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
  return cv2.resize(img,(16,16), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)


def prep_data(images):
  m = len(images)
  n_x = 16*16*3

  X = np.ndarray((n_x,m), dtype=np.uint8)
  y = np.zeros((1,m))
  print("X.shape is {}".format(X.shape))

  for i,image_file in enumerate(images) :
    image = read_image(image_file)
    X[:,i] = np.squeeze(image.reshape((n_x,1)))
    if image_file[72:-3].isupper() :
      y[0,i] = 1
    else :
      y[0,i] = 0

  return X,y
X_train,y_train = prep_data(train_data)
X_test,y_test = prep_data(test_data)

error
X.shape is (768, 70)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-3efa5d093ab3> in <module>()
----> 1 X_train,y_train = prep_data(train_data)
      2 X_test,y_test = prep_data(test_data)

1 frames
<ipython-input-11-86de378ce20c> in read_image(file_path)
      1 def read_image(file_path):
      2   img = cv2.imread(file_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
----> 3   return cv2.resize(img,(16,16),interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
      4 
      5 

error: OpenCV(3.4.3) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:4044: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check path of your images, its wrong.

To verify do the following

```
import sys

def read_image(file_path):
  img = cv2.imread(file_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
  if img is None: 
      print("Couldnt read image")
      sys.exit()
  return cv2.resize(img,(16,16),interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

Check if images are placed in the correct path or not

Comment: could you try printing the shape of the image, after reading it ?

Comment: X.shape is (768, 70)
Couldnt read image
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2890: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)

Comment: Check your `file_path` that is the issue, the file path is wrong

Comment: which syntax do i use

Comment: there is no wrong syntax, your file_path variable should point to a file in your local hard drive, if your path is wrong as in theres no image of that name in that path, then openCV will not give an error, but will rather return None, this means there is no image of that name and path that you have provided.

Comment: still dont understand are you saying there are no images in the folder i specified and how do i fix this

Comment: this is my collab link to the full code https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MKS8x9fp_hp13HYHOb9pWT-wIZ3Mpczq

Comment: Could you please share some sample data, from train_data, i cant run google colab

Comment: how do i do this

Comment: just print the contents of train_data, and share the first 3 indices

Answer (score -1):

While reshaping the image convert it to float32 .

```
img =  X[:,i] = np.squeeze(image.reshape((n_x,1))).astype('float32')
```

Comment: That is very clearly where the error did not generate from, and is not the answer to the OPs question

Comment: While reshaping the images we need to change the images to float32 . This could be the issue .

Comment: Firstly, no you dont need to. You can reshape uint8 as it is. Conversion to float32 might be necessary if the neural network accepts it, but thats a different story. Secondly the code doesn't even reach that part of the code, it throws an error before it, so no this is def not the issue